# Passing string argument in golang

Tags: go

just starting with Go and having trouble with basic function call:

```
fileContentBytes := ioutil.ReadFile("serverList.txt")
fileContent := string(fileContentBytes)
serverList := strings.Split(fileContent,"\n")
   /*
serverList:
server1,
server2,
server3
   */
for _,server := range serverList {
   fmt.Println("sending ", server)
   processServer(server)
}

func processServer(s string) {
   fmt.Println(s, " : started processing")
}
```

Output:

```
sending server1
 : started processing
sending server2
 : started processing
sending server3
 server3: started processing
```

In the above code from the for loop I am able to print all the elements of array but *only the last element* gets passed properly to the function `processServer`.

What am I doing wrong?

Go Version: 1.8
OS: Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you please provide the code, which defines the `serverList` variable?

Or else, you can use the below snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func processServer(s string) {
   fmt.Println(s, " : started processing")
}

func main() {
serverList := [...]string{"server1","server2","server3"}

for _,server := range serverList {
   fmt.Println("sending ", server)
   processServer(server)
}
}
```

You can run the script here: https://play.golang.org/p/EL9RgIO67n

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the relevant code

Comment: ok, issue solved I added a `strings.TrimSpace` before calling the `processServer` function. I guess it was sending the string variable with `\r` as end of lines in windows will have them as well.

Comment: Nice. I am happy that you figured it out.